# Combining three select statements to provide single output

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to pull out a report for DB Roles in Oracle Database which needs to `select "DB Name", "Hostname", Grantee, Granted_role`. For this purpose three selects were prepared:

```
select name from v$database;

select host_name from v$instance;

select distinct(grantee), granted_role from dba_role_privs order by 1;
```

Question is is it possible to combine these and generate a single reporting table:

```
Server-Name;DB name;Role;Userid
```

Could anybody please give any hints?
Thanks!

Comment: Read about joins

Comment: `DISTINCT` is **not a function**. It's a part of `SELECT DISTINCT`, and applies to the whole selected rows. Skip those redundant parentheses and simply write `select distinct grantee, granted_role from ...` to make things clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using joins, but scalar subquery caching means that using a scalar subquery in the select list may be faster, since they get queried once and then the values reused for all the rows, e.g.:

```
SELECT DISTINCT (SELECT NAME
             FROM   v$database) db_name,
            (SELECT host_name
             FROM   v$instance) host_name,
            grantee,
            granted_role
FROM   dba_role_privs
ORDER  BY 1;
```